# Bought a used ledger nano s from Amazon / Ebay. How do you factory reset the Ledger Nano S?

Tags: wallet-security, hardware-wallet, ledger-hardware-wallet

I just bought a used ledger nano s from amazon and ebay. What is the best method of wiping this device and factory reset it? What are some other precautions before using this used device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CryptoSec.info](https://CryptoSec.info) has a complete and updated guide for this specific problem.

To summarize the article, here are the two methods to restore your Ledger Nano S/X:

> 1. Open your device and Navigate to **Settings** > **Device** > **Reset all**
> 2. Enter the wrong PIN three times

For the full detailed guide, check out: [How To Reset Your Ledger Nano S/Nano X](https://cryptosec.info/how-to-reset-ledger-wallet/)

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE. While this link may answer the question, it would be [preferable](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to include quotes from the linked site that explain what to do. Links can disappear and their contents change.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Nano S Configuration Guide](https://support.ledgerwallet.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000613793-Ledger-Nano-S-configuration-guide):

> How to erase or reset your Ledger Nano S?
>
> If you acquired a second-hand Ledger Nano S, or if you want to create
> a second wallet, follow this tutorial to learn how to reset your
> device first.
>
> 1. Connect your Ledger Nano S
> 2. Enter a wrong PIN code and validate by
>    pressing both buttons
> 3. Repeat the 2nd step two more times
> 4. Once your Nano S displays the message "Your device has been reset", press both buttons until the "Welcome" message is displayed, or disconnect and reconnect your device.
>
> Then you will be able to [restore a wallet](https://support.ledgerwallet.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005165309-How-to-import-recover-a-backup-on-a-Nano-S-) or create a new one.

Also keep in mind that your device may have been tampered with and does not contain genuine hardware. You will want to read [this guide](https://support.ledgerwallet.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005321449-How-to-verify-the-security-integrity-of-my-Nano-S-) to ensure that your hardware is genuine.